# html tables & inline styles

Tags: html, css, html-table, html-email

I don't have a lot of experience with HTML tables and in-line CSS, but I'm trying to create an HTML email signature. Ideally, I'd like to have a small image on the left, text in the center, and a larger logo on the right, with a line of text centered below everything.

I have the basic content in, however I've tried to align everything with floats which don't seem to be working. What's the best way to have everything lined up in order horizontally?

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BcZp6/)

```
<br />
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
<table width='600' id="sig" cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0' border-spacing='0' style="margin:0;padding:0;">
<tr>
<td width="47" style="float:left;width:47px;margin:0;padding:0;">
<a href='http://example.com' style="border:none;text-decoration:none;"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/47/43/" alt="First Last" style="border:none;width:47px;"></a>
</td>

<td width="10" style="width:10px;">&nbsp;</td>  

<td valign='top' style="margin:0;padding:0;">
<table id="sig2" cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0' border-spacing='0' style="float:left;padding:0;margin:0;font-family:'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Calibri, sans-serif;font-size:13px;color:#D31145;border-collapse:collapse;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;">
<tr style="margin:0;padding:0;color:#000104;">
<td style="margin:0;padding-left:8px;font-family:'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Calibri, sans-serif;font-size:16px;white-space:nowrap;"><a style="border:none;text-decoration:none;color:#D31145;" href="mailto:email@example.com">FIRST LAST</a>
</td>
</tr>

<tr style="margin:0;padding:0;color:#000104;">
<td style="margin:0;padding-left:8px;font-family:'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Calibri, sans-serif;font-size:16px;white-space:nowrap;">
<span style="border:none;text-decoration:none;color:#000104;">REALTOR | P <a style="border:none;text-decoration:none;color:#000104;" href="tel:1111111111">111.111.1111</a></span>
</td>
</tr>

<td width="177" style="float:right;width:177px;margin:0;padding:0;">
<a href='http://example.com' style="border:none;text-decoration:none;"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/177/54/" alt="ZOPA Realty Group" style="border:none;width:177px;"></a>
</td>
</table>

<table width='600' id="sig" cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0' border-spacing='0' style="margin:-15 0 0 60;padding:0;">
<tr>
<td><span style="margin:0;padding-left:8px;font-size:7px;font-family:'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Calibri, sans-serif;color:#000104;white-space:nowrap;">BRE xxxxxxxx | Broker BRE xxxxxxxx. In association with Keller Williams.  Each Keller Williams Realty office is independently owned and operated.</span></td>

<br />
&nbsp;
```

[image: example]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Forget float, margin and html 3/5. The mail is very obsolete. You need do all with table. 
One line = one table. You need margin or padding ? Do another column.

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Izpig)

Example : i need one line with 
1 One Picture of 40*40
2 One margin of 10 px
3 One text of 400px

I start my line :

```
<table style=" background-repeat:no-repeat; width:450px;margin:0;" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
   <tr style="height:40px; width:450px; margin:0;">
     <td style="height:40px; width:40px; margin:0;">
        <img src="" style="width=40px;height40;margin:0;display:block"
     </td>
     <td style="height:40px; width:10px; margin:0;">        
     </td>
     <td style="height:40px; width:400px; margin:0;">
     <p style=" margin:0;"> my text   </p>
     </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Could you please clarify?

Comment: If you use float or position. You will have good result on webmail (gmail, yahoo etc...) but outlook have the same html reader since 2007. He just understand table. Don't forget to reset margin. Have a nice day !

Comment: What you're saying makes sense, however even in your example Codepen the problem persists.. the larger image is on the bottom when it should be in line horizontally.

Comment: Plz, post a screen of the result that you want. I don't understand :s

Comment: Thank you for your help; please see my original question for an image mockup.

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick:

```
<table width="400" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td width="50" height="40" valign="top" rowspan="3">
      <img alt="" src="" width="40" height="40" style="margin: 0; border: 0; padding: 0; display: block;">
    </td>
    <td width="350" height="40" style="font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; color: #000000;">
<a href="" style="color: #D31145; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: none;">LAST FIRST</a><br>
REALTOR | P 123.456.789
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="350" height="70" valign="bottom" style="font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; color: #000000;">
<img alt="" src="" width="200" height="60" style="margin: 0; border: 0; padding: 0; display: block;">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="350" height="20" valign="bottom" style="font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 10px; color: #000000;">
all your minor text here | all your minor text here | all your minor text here
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

---

UPDATE: Adjusted code per the comments:

After viewing your jsFiddle, an important thing to note about tables is that table cell widths in each additional row all have to be the same width as the first, and all cells must add to the total width of your table.

Here is an example that will NOT WORK:

```
<table width="600" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td width="200" bgcolor="#252525">&nbsp;
    </td>
    <td width="400" bgcolor="#454545">&nbsp;
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="300" bgcolor="#252525">&nbsp;
    </td>
    <td width="300" bgcolor="#454545">&nbsp;
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Although the 2nd row does add up to 600, it (and any additional rows) must have the same 200-400 split as the first row, unless you are using colspans. If you use a colspan, you could have one row, but it needs to have the same width as the cells it is spanning, so this works:

```
<table width="600" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td width="200" bgcolor="#252525">&nbsp;
    </td>
    <td width="400" bgcolor="#454545">&nbsp;
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="600" colspan="2" bgcolor="#353535">&nbsp;
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Not a full tutorial, but I hope that helps steer you in the right direction in the future.

Here is the code you are after:

```
<table width="900" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td width="57" height="43" valign="top" rowspan="2">
      <img alt="Rashel Adragna" src="http://zoparealtygroup.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/sig_head.png" width="47" height="43" style="margin: 0; border: 0; padding: 0; display: block;">
    </td>
    <td width="843" height="43" style="font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; color: #000000;">
<a href="" style="color: #D31145; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: none;">RASHEL ADRAGNA</a><br>
REALTOR | P 855.900.24KW
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="843" height="64" valign="bottom" style="font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; color: #000000;">
<img alt="Zopa Realty Group logo" src="http://zoparealtygroup.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/sig_logo.png" width="177" height="54" style="margin: 0; border: 0; padding: 0; display: block;">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="843" colspan="2" height="20" valign="bottom" align="center" style="font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 10px; color: #000000;">
all your minor text here | all your minor text here | all your minor text here
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

You'll note that I've added an extra 10px to some of your table cells. This in combination with align/valigns act as padding between your cells. It is a clever way to aviod actually having to add padding, margins or empty padding cells.

Comment: After inserting my own images/values, I've run into the same problem as before http://jsfiddle.net/A3d9b/

Comment: Which problem was that? Alignments? A screenshot may help.

Comment: See my original question for a mockup of how I'd like it to work - everything in line horizontally, with one line of text centered below.